# Interative Brokers: using ibPy to get live market data

Tags: interactive-brokers

documentation on ibPy is sparse. All I would like to do is request the current price of a security both pre-market and during market hours so that I can make automated trading decision on that information.

Something like:

```
get_price("AAPL"....)
```

that returns the current price of AAPL. Any pointers, or documentation links are much appreciated.